Is it possible for a neighbor to forget his hat while his wife isn't home, and if so what should I let them in?
In That Is Not My Neighbor, some neighbors can forget their hats at home, in which case you should call their wife.
Can they come home without their hat while their wife isn't home, and if so should I let them in or call DDD?

This seems like a very random question. I haven’t played the game, so I wouldn’t know if this is important or not, but is there a specific reason you’re asking?

does stack exchange require a specific reason? also want to know if such a situation could happen so I can be prepared for it

@Daemons It's a game where you're judging whether someone is the real person or an alien impostor, and little things like this are clues. I've only watched a little, so no idea if this is an actual possibility or just a theoretical from OP.

@Dave Sometimes, if questions are completely random and don’t seem to serve a purpose (for example, a recent recent-ish question asked smth about if there’s a normal water tile anywhere in a Portal level. That question was downvoted because it seemed useless to everyone, until the person clarified and the question was received better). Obviously, I didn’t know anything about the game so I didn’t know if this was important, but for some questions this is definitely something you’ll want to do.

I want to know what to do if that did happen, but I was afraid that would make it two question, which is another violation

from the wiki

If he forgets his hat while Lois is currently absent, Roman will state
that he forget his hat at home, but no one is at the apartment at the
moment and the player has to trust him. In this case (assuming the
papers and appearance are fine otherwise), he is not a doppelganger.


If he forgets his hat while Rafttellyn is currently absent, Alf will
state that he forget his hat at home, but no one is at the apartment
at the moment and the player has to trust him. In this case (assuming
the papers and appearance are fine otherwise), he is not a
doppelganger.


According to the fandom wiki for the Hatless attribute:

2 (or more) characters may or may not be a doppleganger if they don't have their hat. It says "like [char 1], [char 2]" which implies there are more than just those two.
1 character is always a doppleganger if they don't have a hat.
4 characters can never be hatless.
1 character always wears a hat in photos.
In Nightmare Mode 2 characters can never be hatless, and always wear it in photos.

Made vague to prevent spoilers, just in case, as the characters are directly named on the wiki page.
There's no mention of anyone's wife/husband/etc being home or not, so that doesn't seem to matter to the game. But it looks like, yes, this can be used to identify a doppleganger, and they will be "caught red handed" (using the wiki terminology).

I know what it says on the wiki, but I know the correct course of action if Roman Stilnsky or Alf Cappuccin comes home without their hat is to call their wife to confirm they don't have their hat, what I'm asking is what to do if their wife isn't home either

you know, even though you didn't answer what I wanted to know, you refencing the wiki made to check their pages again, thanks

No problem. Hadn't considered digging for more specific info as I thought it was more general and less specific.
